# To show growth and shrinkage of a filament using animation in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Here's a simple code that demonstrates what I want to do. The dot is the tip of the  filament, that grows and shrinks randomly. When the shrinkage happens, I want the line to shrink too, instead of retracing the already visible longer line(basically at each step of the animation, the dot should be visible as the end point of the line ). The tip represents whether the filament is growing or shrinking.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,6,5,4,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,6,5,4,3,4,5,6,7,8]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xlim([0, 20])
ax.set_ylim([-1.1, 20])


graph, = ax.plot([], [], color = ''green)
dot, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', color='green', markersize = 4)

def oj(i):

    graph.set_data(X[:i+1],Y[:i+1])

    dot.set_data(X[i],Y[i])

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, oj, frames=len(X), interval=1000,repeat 
= False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You have a typo: It's `color = 'green'` instead of `color = ''green`.

Comment: Sorry, the typo was something I made while writing the question, the main problem is with the animation. I want the filaments to grow and shrink in the animation.

Comment: x=[1,2,3,4] grows, x=[4,3,2,1] shrinks, x=[1,2,3,4,3,2,1] grows and shrinks.

Comment: The problem is when the filament shrinks, the dot retraces back while the line remains of constant length, I want the line to reduce in length as the dot retraces back its path. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJKXNarWpqE

Comment: ^ This might help visualise what I want to show through the animation.

Comment: Maybe you want `graph.set_data([X[0],X[i]],[Y[0],Y[i]])`?

Comment: Thank you :). It was very silly to set X[:i]. This works.